# Proof of Pearson's chi squared test

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, weak-convergence

i was reading proof of this theorem on http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2003/lecture-notes/lec23.pdf

They showed, that $\frac{v_j-np_j}{\sqrt{np_j}} \stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow} N(0,1-p_j)$. I don't understand however why

$\sum_{j=1}^r \frac{(v_j-np_j)^2}{np_j} \stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow} \sum_{i=1}^r Z_i^2$

holds?

I know that if $X_n \stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow} X$, then for every continuous function $f$ we have $f(X_n) \stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow} f(X)$, so $\frac{(v_j-np_j)^2}{np_j} \stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow} Z_j^2$. But I know as well, that it's not true that $X_n \stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow} X$ and $Y_n \stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow} Y$ imply $X_n+Y_n \stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow} X+Y$.

Comment: Sorry, the page you requested was not found.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent then it's true: the characteristic function of $X_n + Y_n$ is $E[e^{iu(X_n + Y_n)}] = E[e^{iuX_n}]E[e^{iuY_n}]$

Since $X_n$ and $Y_n$ converge in distribution to $X$ and $Y$, we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} E[e^{iu(X_n + Y_n)}] = E[e^{iuX}]E[e^{iuY}] =E[e^{iu(X + Y)}] $$

Since the characteristic function of $X_n + Y_n$ is tending to the characteristic function of $X + Y$, you can conclude that $$X_n + Y_n \stackrel{D}{\longrightarrow} X+Y$$

Comment: I'm a bit late to the game, but for the application in the question $\nu_{1},\ldots,\nu_{r}$ are not independent ($\sum_{i}^{r}\nu_{i}=n$) so I'm not sure this answer actually answers the question.

Answer (score 9):

If we write $Z_i = \frac{O_i-np_i}{\sqrt{np_i}}$ as in the leture notes, the idea is that the vector $Z\to\mathcal N(0,\Sigma)$, a multivariate normal distribution, where

$$\Sigma=\text{Cov}(Z)=\begin{bmatrix}
1-p_1 & -\sqrt{p_1 p_2} & \cdots \\
-\sqrt{p_1 p_2} & 1-p_2 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}.$$

If we compute $\text{Det}(\Sigma-\lambda I)=(1-\lambda)^{n-1}\lambda$ we get that $\Sigma$ has $n-1$ eigenvalues that are 1 and one that is 0.
(The computation is made easy by the fact that $\Sigma=I-pp^T$ for $p=(\sqrt{p_1},\sqrt{p_2},\dots)$, and [Sylvester's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Sylvester.27s_determinant_theorem).)

This means the distribution is really $n-1$ dimensional embedded in $n$ dimensions, and there is a rotation matrix $A$ that makes

$$A\Sigma A^T=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now let $X = AZ \sim N(0,A\Sigma A^T)$. Then $X$ is a vector $(0, X_1, X_2, \dots)$ of iid. $\mathcal N(0,1)$ gaussians.
The function $f(Z) = Z_1^2 + Z_2^2 + \dots$ is the norm $\|Z\|_2^2$, and hence it doesn't change when we rotate its argument. This means $f(Z) = f(AZ) = f(X) = 0^2 + X_1^2 + \dots$,
which is Chi-square distributed!

Pretty cool stuff. Thank you for pointing me towards this result :-)

Comment: Excellent! You really solve the point which I got stuck in. Do you know which book (not a lecture note) I can find the same proof?

Comment: Why the first component $X_0$ of $\mathbf{X}$ is $0$? I think $(A\Sigma A^T)_{11}=0$ only implies that $Var(X_0)=0$.

Comment: If a random variable has variance 0 it is a constant. If it also has mean 0, it must be the constant 0.

Comment: Thanks. I've come up with a proof last night. Check that $\mathbf{p}^T \mathbf{Z}=0$. Then $\Sigma \mathbf{Z}=(I-\mathbf{p} \mathbf{p}^T)\mathbf{Z}=\mathbf{Z}-\mathbf{p}\mathbf{p}^T\mathbf{Z}=\mathbf{Z}$. Note that $A\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}0&O\\O&I\end{bmatrix}A$. Therefore, $\mathbf{X}=A\mathbf{Z}=A(\Sigma \mathbf{Z})=(A\Sigma) \mathbf{Z}=\begin{bmatrix}0&O\\O&I\end{bmatrix}A\mathbf{Z}$ and $X_1=0$.

Comment: This should be the correct proof.

Comment: Good direction, but there should be one more step. Computing the eigen values (0 and 1) alone does not imply that a rotation matrix $A$ exists, because the eigen-space of the eigen-value $1$ is not necessarily $k-1$. Instead, one should use the fact that because $\Sigma$ is symmetric, it is unitarily diagonalizable and therefore $A$ exists, with $A \Sigma A^T$ being a diagonal matrix consisting of 1 and 0 along the diagonal.

Comment: @ThomasAhle On a side note, there is this Arxiv paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.09171.pdf (end page 5 to start page 6) that has such similar wording as your answer. It was uploaded in 2018 but your answer was from 2017, so maybe they somehow paraphrased your answer without acknowledgement?

Comment: @Student I assume Pearson's proof in 1900 was already along the same lines as my proof :-)

Comment: @ThomasAhle Possibly :) Would you agree with my previous comment regarding eigen-space, or is there something I am missing so it wasn't necessary?

Comment: @darkgbm I think you are right about the symmetric claim. I guess this has something to do with Jordan blocks and Geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue. For Chi-square distribution on i.i.d., [Cochran's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Properties) construct the rotation matrix $A$ with eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

In the attached paper Z_i is distributed N(0,1-p_i) for all i as stated in the paper (underscore is used to denote subscripts here). So since (v_i - np_i)/sqrt(np_i) converges to N(0,1-p_i) for all i, we have that (v_i - np_i)^2/np_i converges to (Z_i)^2 for all I. That should clear up the first part.

Also it turns out that X_n -> X and Y_n -> Y does imply X_n + Y_n -> X + Y.

Proof: let eps > 0 be given and choose N sufficiently large such that 
|X_n - X|,|Y_n - Y| < eps/2 for all n >= N. Then 
|(X_n - X) + (Y_n - Y)| <= |X_n - X| + |Y_n - Y| < eps/2 + eps/2 = eps for all n >= N. Since eps > 0 was chosen arbitrarily, we have that X_n + Y_n -> X + Y.

Comment: It is convergence in distribution, not pointwise. Your proof is flawed